# Mongodb bulk insert costs

Tags: performance, mongodb

Mongo db has two ways of bulk inserting documents, using:

- The [`db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp) method.
- The [`insert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/) method and passing an array of documents, where inserts are unordered by default.

Is the latter faster than the former, if only bulk inserts are considered?

Comment: What results did you get when you tested both methods?

Comment: Well I've tested this a bit myself since I've asked this question and it appears that `insert` is about 2x faster using pymongo at least in my project, but haven't tested it properly yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the shell or about the Python driver? They could implement the methods a bit differently from each other. For the shell, you can just type in `db.collection.insert` and see the code for this function. Doing that, you'll see that it essentially just makes a bulk operation out of the insert, so in the shell they should be equivalent in performance.

Comment: Thanks, I thought `insert` was implemented in the binary.